# Heroku not working and I don't know where to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I apologize for this being a vague question but I don't know what is going wrong so I don't know how to ask the questions.

I set up a rails app and it's working locally.  However, when creating it on Heroku Create and it gets set up on my Heroku server it does not work.  When I run Heroku open I get this page:

https://polar-taiga-65467.herokuapp.com/

I can post logs or anything else to help.  If someone can help me figure out what to do from here it would be appreciated.

Here is my GitHub project: https://github.com/TomTom319/morali-tee

Here is the log from Heroku:

```
2018-01-16T05:13:18.292500+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.292411 #4]  INFO -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]   Rendering simple_pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-01-16T05:13:18.295106+00:00 app[web.1]:
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]     3:  2018-01-16T05:13:18.293930+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.293863 #4]  INFO -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]   Rendered simple_pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2018-01-16T05:13:18.294179+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.294089 #4]  INFO -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms 2018-01-16T05:13:18.294881+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.294798 #4] FATAL -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]    2018-01-16T05:13:18.295107+00:00 app[web.1]:
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]     4: <%= image_tag("yellowtee", class: "img-responsive first-tee")%>
2018-01-16T05:13:18.295101+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.295028 #4] FATAL -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]     1: <h1 style="color:red;">MoraliTee</h1> 2018-01-16T05:13:18.295104+00:00
app[web.1]: [99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]     2: <p>Welcome! We are on a mission to give back to people around the world</p>
2018-01-16T05:13:18.295158+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
[2018-01-16T05:13:18.295086 #4] FATAL -- :
[99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55]    2018-01-16T05:13:18.760114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
path="/favicon.ico" host=polar-taiga-65467.herokuapp.com
request_id=6a2ec4b7-7054-46b7-b76a-28ef5ab3f69a fwd="24.15.217.85"
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2018-01-16T05:13:18.293286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
path="/" host=polar-taiga-65467.herokuapp.com
request_id=99bf3dd0-59b3-4438-a3f7-36a037174b55 fwd="24.15.217.85" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=1827
protocol=https
```

`Simple_pages/index.html.erb` code below:

```
<h1 style="color:red;">MoraliTee</h1>
<p>Welcome! We are on a mission to give back to people around the 
world</p>

<%= image_tag("yellowtee", class: "img-responsive first-tee")%>
```

Comment: You can post it, so post it. Why not?

Comment: In your command line, run `heroku logs -t -a name-of-app`. The `-t` option is for tailing the Heroku logs. Once you've spotted the error, Google it and attempt to implement a solution. If you get stuck, update your question. If Googling has given you what you need, please close this question. Or, better yet, answer it yourself with the steps you took to fix the issue.

Comment: I uploaded the logs and I see a fatal error is that the number I should google?

Comment: Have you ran the migration scripts..?

Comment: I ran $ heroku run rails db:migrate

Comment: Seems like Heroku is having an issue with your `simple_pages/index.html.erb` view. Could you post the code for that file? Also, please use the formatting tools when editing your question to improve readability.

Comment: I just added thank you for taking a look

Answer (score 1):

There was a file type missing from the end of my image on my simple_pages/index.html.erb page.  I needed to .jpg to the end of my source in my image_tag.

Thank you @mmichael for your help in identifying the issue.

I thought there was something wrong with my db but I was incorrect.  Thanks for your help.